# adding days to a variable date in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am new to xsl but I saw a few posts on here about using umbraco library to add days to a date in xsl but it is not working for me. I am trying to calculate delivery date by adding 20days to order date, I am using xsl version 1.0

Thank you all in advance

XSL
  `<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:DateAdd('$orderdate', 'd', 20)"/>`

XML
    `<orderdate>20130722</orderdate>`

I am trying to get my result as `<orderdate>20130811</orderdate>` but it is coming through as `<orderdate>20130742</orderdate>`

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you've tried and what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the date you fed as the parameter, it might not be recognized; as `2009-06-27T18:38:32` is the string that **currentDate** method returns. I assume the parameter `string Date`  in `DateAdd(string Date, string AddType, int add)` must be of similar format or must be converted to it using the format methods?!?